# Can't get conversion to work

Tags: javascript

I can't get my conversion equation to work. Looking to convert light years to yottameters for a project. I'm very new to this, and I need some assistance. Thank you for understanding.

```
var year = 0
var universe =  0
var speed = 0
var yottameters = 0
var widthinYM = 0

document.getElementByID('widthinYM').value = widthinYM;
var year = 365.25
var universe =  156,000,000,000
var speed = 299,792,458 x math.pow (60,2)x 24
var yottameters = math.pow (10,-24)
var widthinYM = speed * universe * year * yottameters;
```

Comment: What is the number you expect and what is the number you are getting?

Comment: Your commas and operators are wrong, as well as your order of execution.

Comment: This whole program is incorrect. Variables declared several times, lower-case m in Math.pow, commas within the numbers, `document.getElementById` with an uppercase D, I suggest you take some time to learn JS first

Comment: Yes this is the first time I'm attempting to write it myself. I did something earlier yesterday, but can't seem to wrap myself around this one for some reason.

Comment: The commas [probably aren't doing what you are expecting them to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `,` like that in JS numbers, and multiplication is done with `*`, not `x`. Also you need to capitalize `Math`.

`156,000,000,000` collapses to `0`.

```
var year = 365.25;
var universe =  156000000000;
var speed = 299792458 * Math.pow(60, 2) * 24;
var yottameters = Math.pow(10, -24);
var widthinYM = speed * universe * year * yottameters;

document.getElementById('widthinYM').value = widthinYM;
```

Comment: My answer was silly, I ran the equations after fixing them, and then saw your answer ha

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am attempting to teach myself as I'm used to HTML and have no experience with JavaScript. Bought myself a textbook and thought I'd try out some stuff for myself.

Comment: `document.getElementByID` the d in `ID` is capitalised, it should be lowercase (Id).

Comment: @Neaox Good call, thanks!

Comment: So, would I use the return statement to return the value in the function then? Such as

    function myFunction()
    {corrected code;
     return = x ;
     }